# How can you specify the coordinates that you want a bitmap to appear on a canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, bitmapimage

Given a bitmap:

```
Swamp1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Swamp-Corner-Transparent.png"));
```

How can I specify the coordinates that it will appear on a canvas:

```
<Canvas Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="822"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1198" Name="MainCanvas">
    <Image  Name="MapBorderSource" />
</Canvas>
```

I've done this before, but it was a long time ago. Specifically, I need to draw the `BitmapImage` 'Swamp1' at the coordinates X,Y of the `Canvas` 'MainCanvas' on top of the `Image` 'MapBorderSource'. The PNG has white set to Alpha 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code behind, you would write

```
var image = new Image
{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
        "pack://application:,,,/Images/Swamp-Corner-Transparent.png"));
};
Canvas.SetLeft(image, x);
Canvas.SetTop(image, y);
MainCanvas.Children.Add(image);
```

If you need to put the new Image directly on top of `MapBorderSource`, below any possible other child elements, you could write

```
var index = MainCanvas.Children.IndexOf(MapBorderSource) + 1;
MainCanvas.Children.Insert(index, image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify coordinates like this..

```
 <Image  Name="MapBorderSource" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10" />
```